# Why does Ruby expression with double ampersand using a return statement cause a syntax error

Tags: ruby, operators, syntax-error, expression, operator-precedence

```
def foo
  true && return false
end

def bar
  true and return false
end
```

`foo` method causes a syntax error. `bar` doesn't. Why?

Assuming I want to evaluate one-liners with a return statement (similar to a certain commonly used shell/bash expression), would this be a recommended way to do it, or is there a more recommended approach?

Comment: my suspicion is that the interpreter evaluates the expression: ((true && return) false)

Comment: The two answers below say it's because of precedence or associativity strength (`&&` > `and`), but can anyone explain why `return` falls between them? Why doesn't `return` always take the argument/value following it no matter what?

Comment: @iamnotmaynard If my answer is one of the two that you mention, then you are interpreting the answer wrong. (And probably so for Simone Carletti's answer as well.) I am not saying that `&&` has precedence over `and`. I am (implicitly, using the example) saying that `&&` has precedence over `return`'s method call (which takes its argument).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Side Note**

It is worth noting that `and` and `&&` are not equivalent.

`and` is a flow control operator while `&&` is a Boolean operator. What is the difference?

One example of the differences, using `and`, you can assign values.

```
value = nil and value / 42
```

This would fail if you tried it as below

```
value = nil && value / 42
```

**Original Question 1**

> Assuming I want to evaluate one-liners with a return statement (similar to a certain > commonly used shell/bash expression), would this be a recommended way to do it, or is there > a more recommended approach?

The way I have always seen this done in Ruby is this:

```
value if conditional
```

This will return the value if the conditional is met and `nil` otherwise. No need for the `return` statement if this is the last command in the function!

If you are using this for an early exit to a function, I prefer using an `unless`. For instance...

```
return unless arguments_are_valid
```

**Original Question 2**

> foo method causes a syntax error. bar doesn't. Why?

It's a matter of operator precedence. See the example below showing how they are evaluated.

```
(true && return) false
(true) and (return false)
```

Comment: Best answer because it answers the question and gives examples / use cases. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

By operator associativity strength,

```
true && return false
```

evaluates to

```
(true && return) false
```

of which

```
true && return
```

is valid, but the `false` after it is invalid. You cannot have two statements lined up without anything in between.

Comment: To add to this, the `and` is a lower precedence than `&&`, so as @sawa points out, this is the reason `foo` doesn't work but `bar` does, because `bar` evaluates as you expect it to.

Answer (score 3):

Because of the `&&` operator precedence, the following line

```
true && return false
```

evaluates as

```
(true && return) false
```

that does not makes sense. In order to execute your code you need to use

```
def foo
  true && (return false)
end
```

`and` doesn't suffer of the same issue because [`and` has lower precedence than `&&`](http://phrogz.net/ProgrammingRuby/language.html#table%5F18.4).

Answer (score 0):

if there is need for shorten statements use

```
def foo
  return false if true
end

def bar
  return false if true
end
```

return is not a function :) therefore it doesn't make sense to say

```
when true and return is ok send a false
```